# Using a variable as a range name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where the user can input a list of cell references as hardcoded values in cells. The VBA script is then supposed to take that input and work with the values in those exact cells in two separate worksheets. So for instance the input looks like the following:

```
Input
G29
H38
M92
```

The script is then supposed to loop through the range on input (in this case G29, H38 and M92) and go into a separate workbook (source workbook) where it then copies the values in those exact cells and then goes into another separate workbook (target workbook) and paste the values into the same cell references.

In the following code I have defined the variables as follows:

wsKpInput_source = The relevant worksheet in the source workbook

wsSCEInput_target = The relevant worksheet in the target workbook

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Dashboard!E9:E11") 'This is the G29,H38,M92 input from the user    
Dim cell_source As Range  'To take the references input by the user (G29,H38,M92) - unsure how to define this?
Dim cell_source_input As Variant 'To use the cell references in cell_source and be put equal to the content in that source workbook cell reference

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    cell_source = rng.Cells(i, 1)
    cell_source_input = wsKpInput_source.Range(cell_source)
    wsKpInput_target.Range(cell_source) = cell_source_input
Next
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as intended and I believe it is probably due to several issues? I would much appreciate any help with this.

Comment: `cell_source` needs to be a variant, or `set cell_source=rng.cells(I,1)` then `.range(cell_source.value)` would wokr

Comment: Thank you for assisting but unfortunately even when including this change I still get an error at the definition of the cell_source_input variable. It seems like it still won't execute the wsKpInput_source.Range(cell_source) line

Comment: No worries, If youre sure :)

Comment: So what I said was right :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done properly on one single line as so:

```
Sub copy()
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Dashboard!E9:E11")  'This is the G29,H38,M92 input from the user
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

    wsKpInput_target.Range(rng.Cells(i, 1).Value).Value = wsKpInput_source.Range(rng.Cells(i, 1).Value).Value
Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that you tried `.rng.cells(I,1)` which will return a cell reference of that cell, where you needed the value within the cell as a cell reference (done with `.value`). Also copying from one cell to another can always be done with one line on two sides of an `=` statement.

Also this method is not the most efficient as it can probably done with adding all values to an array at one time, but that would probably take more time coding than you would save.